# Plesk 12 Domain Alias

Tags: redirect, joomla, dns, alias

Lately, my hosting has moved from a Plesk Panel 9 to Plesk Panel 12. The problem is, that I have a main domain (dd-orange.gr) and 4 alias to it.

The problem is that when someone visits dd-orange.com he's getting a 301 redirect no matter what I do. I have even changed the base tag, the database references from dd-orange.gr to .com, anything.

I don't think it's a Joomla related issue as it's happening right away, on a placeholder .html file that first appears when you visit dd-orange.gr!

Please help me solve the problem, or at least strike out the sources from which it might have originated.

Thank you so much in advance!
Nikos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of a default redirect to the primary domain. See the following link: [Alias redirects](https://support.managed.com/kb/a2075/after-adding-domain-alias-plesk-12-alias-redirects.aspx)